# How can I inspect queries to/from a canvas element?

Tags: https, html5-canvas, web-inspector

I was checking how does VMWare remote console work inside ESXI and I found out that you can not inspect the queries sent from that console.

Once the DOM is rendered I can comunicate with the server and send commands with my keyboard to the server and I receive an answer.

I can not see any updates in the DOM, this question is already answered in other places, the canvas just draws things inside without modifying the HTML element, and there seem to be some 3rd party tools to be able to follow those changes.

But how does it work on the network side? I do not see any query in the inspector, but I´m 100% sure it is communicating with the server, as I'm typing to the server and receiving the output of the commands.

If I use wireshark to monitor the network I just see some TLS queries.

Is there any way to monitor what is happening there inside the browser?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of the tool you are talking about.

> HTML5 Canvases cannot be **"Inspected"**

You cannot see the separate elements in it. It is one single raster rendering. Just like you mentioned in your question. It is just a rendering, There are no separate elements in it to be inspected.

There are techniques to make it interactive, maybe even take in your keyboard input. But all of them involve redrawing the entire canvas on every tiny pixel update.

Now, To answer your main question:

### Network Tab

If you wanna see the communication with the server, see the **Network tab** in Chrome dev tools. It should show every request sent from your web application.

Comment: I´m aware of the network tab, but the request done in the canvas are not being logged there. I´ve added an image to show it. I make request like ls in the server but there are no requests at all.

Comment: @nck The console looks like it's in a different window. Are you sure you opened the network tab for the same window?

Comment: yes I´m sure, I just opened in a diferent view two see clearly both thing in paralel and removed the queries from the first download of the page to show the issue. Somehow the queries do not go through the console

Comment: @nck I came across this post with the same question - did you ever figure out how this works/where the activity can be viewed? I'm sure the answer is in some spec doc somewhere but I'm mostly just curious

Comment: @GeonGeorge I can confirm that this is not a conceptual issue w/r/t devtools, for example I have a mapping app that uses mapboxgl & any queries outside of the map canvas show up normally, but the actual data that is getting loaded into the canvas doesn't show any associated activity under the network tab

Comment: @AviNerenberg nope, unfortunately I was not able to find any workaround